# Is it possible to set the visibility of Name on Leads?

Tags: api, permissions

I want to restrict the visibility of the name field on Leads from API access. Is that possible? I know that field level security is possible on other fields but it doesn't seem to be available for Name on Leads

Comment: You can use sharing rules or object level security to prevent an API user (based on profiles/permission sets/OWD) from even seeing all/some leads

Comment: right. that's good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No object's Name field can be hidden or made read-only.